# Join tables in different Databases in AWS RDS Postgres Server

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have 2 databases in one AWS RDS Postgres instance. I would like to join the tables across the databases. Is it possible to do that in AWS RDS ?

What could be the walk around?

I have created extension dblink.

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink
```

And my join query is -

```
SELECT *                                                       
FROM test tb1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=test_db','SELECT id, name FROM test') AS tb2(id, name)) AS tb2 ON tb2.id = tb1.id;
```

I get this error-

```
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 3: LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=test_db','SELECT id,...
```

What could be the issue and fix ?

Thanks

Comment: From a quick glance at [PostgreSQL Cross Database Queries using DbLink - Leeladharan Achar - alias - leelu ~ blogging...hola mi amigos..](http://www.leeladharan.com/postgresql-cross-database-queries-using-dblink), it looks like you need to include **column type** in the table definition (eg `AS tb2(id INTEGER, name CHARACTER VARYING)`).

Comment: Thanks it works now! But is there any other way where I do not have to manually enter the column names of the table while joining ? I understand that dblink requires the name of the columns. For big tables it would be an issue

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Please update your comment. The site you have linked doesn't work anymore and leads to spam...TIA!

Comment: Here's a similar video: [PostgreSQL Cross Database Queries using DBLink Extension - dbrnd.com - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vk712oS0VM)